# If I write two pieces of software that compute the same thing but one does it twice as fast. Does that imply different orders of complexity?

Tags: python, algorithm, python-3.x, complexity-theory

For a given balance and interest rate my programs compute the minimum monthly payment to pay off the debt in a year.
However One computes it on average in ~0.000150s and the other in ~0.000300s. Does that imply different degrees of asymptotic complexity?

These are the code samples:

The slower one:

```
import time
start_time = time.time()

balance = 999999
annualInterestRate = 0.18
mRate = annualInterestRate/12
high = (((mRate+1)**12)*balance)/12
low = balance/12
guessed = False

def balanceLeft(balance,mRate,minPayment):
    monthsLeft = 12
    while monthsLeft > 0:
        unpaidBalance =  balance - minPayment
        interest = mRate * unpaidBalance
        balance = unpaidBalance
        balance += interest
        monthsLeft -= 1
    return balance

while guessed == False:
    minPayment = (high + low) / 2
    if round(balanceLeft(balance,mRate,minPayment),2) < 0:
        high = minPayment
    elif round(balanceLeft(balance,mRate,minPayment),2)> 0:
        low = minPayment
    else:
        if abs(round(balanceLeft(balance,mRate,minPayment),2) - 0) < 0.01:
            guessed = True

print('Lowest Payment: ',end='')
print(round(minPayment,2))

print("time elapsed: {:.6f}s".format(time.time() - start_time))
```

The faster one

```
import time
start_time = time.time()

annualInterestRate = 0.18
rate = annualInterestRate / 12
monthsLeftr = 12
xCoefficent = 1 + rate
ConstantTerm = 1 + rate
while monthsLeftr > 1:
    xCoefficent = (xCoefficent + 1) * ConstantTerm
    monthsLeftr -= 1


balance = 999999
monthsLeft = 12
while monthsLeft > 0:
    balance = balance * ConstantTerm
    monthsLeft -= 1
minPayment = balance / xCoefficent


print('Lowest Payment: ', end="")
print(round(minPayment,2))

print("time elapsed: {:.6f}s".format(time.time() - start_time))
```

Comment: it's in the comments sorry, used up my character limit. "Does it imply that the codes have different degrees of asymptotic complexity"

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Absolutely not.

Asymptotic complexity never describes absolute running times, but the trend when the problem size increases.

In practice, it is extremely frequent that algorithms with a better asymptotic complexity run slower for small problem instances.

Comment: Sorry i was under impressions that it describes the trend in runtime as problem size increases ?

Comment: Not the correct answer - also because they have not same style of functioning. While they may be functionally same - the implementation is different - making 1st one slow and second one fast.

Comment: @ChrisIkeokwu: no, because of the "hidden constant".

Comment: @ChrisIkeokwu:  It (asymptotic complexity) *does* describe the trend in runtime as problem size increases.  However I can have an algorithm that takes 1s for 10 items, and 2s for 100 (it's O(log n)), and another that takes .1s for 10 items and 1s for 100 (it's O(n²)).  However, note that the O(n²) algorithm is actually faster.

Comment: @MartinBonner: it took me a while to see the dot before 1s, and your computation is wrong. Should be 10s.

Comment: @prabodhprakash Oh i understand, while it describes the trend in runtimes it does not necessarily predict the runtimes themselves

Comment: @ChrisIkeokwu: and an algorithm which has O(n³) complexity also has O(1000000000n³) complexity. Also note that the asymptotic behavior only starts after some N, which might be a billion elements.

Comment: @YvesDaoust does that mean the 'n' coefficient is ignored or ?

Comment: @ChrisIkeokwu: actually, you cannot use timing measurements to observe the asymptotic complexity. It must be drawn from theoretical algorithm analysis.

Comment: @ChrisIkeokwu: go and look at the definition of Big-O.

Comment: @YvesDaoust okay this is my 3rd week of any programming or computer science experience. So sorry for seeming like a bumbling fool. Will look it up

Comment: @ChrisIkeokwu: don't take it badly If you want to "play" with the Big-O notation, you must read and understand its definition first.

Comment: @YvesDaoust Can't you time the execution for different problem sizes and and assert complexity for a given algorithm from there ?

Comment: @jadsq: nope. For small N, timing measurements are inaccurate (and when I say small I mean like up to a billion). For larger N, they become infeasible and wrong ! (because the machine becomes slower). But to observe the true asymptotic behavior with some reliability, especially when there are logarithmic factors, you may need to go to... 10^100 or higher. Another obstacle is that the running time is not just a function of N but also of the data set; in theory you can use the worst case; in practice you don't know what it is or are unable to generate it. Complexity is not measurable.

Answer (score 0):

No, they are not same program. The first one has a while loop that calls a function that has another while loop - looks like, both of them has different complexity.

The first one is clearly the slower one (a squared complexity program)- the second one has no such inner loops and is a linear complexity program.

Comment: Before you can declare an `O( f(n) )` complexity, you need to define `n`. I don't think your analysis stands, because the loops iterate over different things.

Comment: I have not declared complexity, there is no mention of any symbols or n anything in my answer- just given an idea of how things would be working. And if they iterate over different stuffs, it would be something like O(m*n). - eligible to produce a slow algorithm.

Answer (score 0):

Translated into a verbal idea, you are trying to solve the linear equation `a-b*x=0`, in the first variant via the bisection method, in the second method via the direct formula `x = a/b`. Purely from the description, the second variant will always be faster, since the first also needs to compute `a` and `b` (resp. `b*x` in every step).

You will often find that for equations where a direct solution formula exists, that running this formula is much faster than any iterative approximation method.

Unfortunately, there are not that much problem classes with direct solution formulas. But as here a linear problem can always be solved directly (the efficiency argument changes for high dimensional linear systems.)